# Why would "the stranger" continuously dress the same way?

Tags: character, the-stranger

All throughout the first season of Netflix's *The Stranger*, the young female that goes around revealing secrets and sometimes blackmailing others to not reveal their secrets always wears the same kind of outfit -- a ball cap, a bomber jacket, her hair down, and tight jeans.

[image]

If she's constantly going around performing these risky and sometimes illegal actions, **why would she always wear the same style outfit only for her to be more easily identifiable by authorities and/or other people?** She and her "partner in crime" seem to be smart about their overall plan and how they conduct their schemes, but this feature isn't consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She doesn't always wear the same clothes:

- She wore a smart outfit to the meeting with Ed Price
- She wore a work uniform while working in a cinema
- She wore a nurse outfit when sneaking in a hospital
- She wears different T-shirts under her jacket
- In the final scene, when she is looking at Price and his boys playing football, she doesn't wear the jacket (I believe a few months has passed and it is warmer)

Yes, she seems to wear the same jacket and a cap most of the times, but it is most likely because she finds those clothes comfortable - she seems to be a sort of a [tomboy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tomboy) in contrast to her more "girly" girlfriend.